# How do I rotate a 3d vector with a 4x4 matrix transform or euler angles?

Tags: ios, matrix, graphics, 3d, scenekit

I have a 3d vector I'm applying as a physics force:

```
let force = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -5)  
node.physicsBody?.applyForce(force, asImpulse: true)
```

I need to rotate the force based on the [mobile device's position](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera) which is available to me as a 4x4 matrix transform or euler angles.

> var transform :matrix_float4x4 - The position and orientation of the camera in world coordinate space.
>
> var eulerAngles :vector_float3 - The orientation of the camera, expressed as roll, pitch, and yaw values.

I think this is more of a fundamental 3d graphics question, but the application of this is a Swift based iOS app using SceneKit and ARKit.

There are some utilities available to me in the [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit) and simd libraries. Unfortunately my naive attempts to do things like `simd_mul(force, currentFrame.camera.transform)` are failing me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@orangenkopf provided a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44749520/537111) that helped me come up with this:

```
let force = simd_make_float4(0, 0, -5, 0)
let rotatedForce = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, force)
let vectorForce = SCNVector3(x:rotatedForce.x, y:rotatedForce.y, z:rotatedForce.z)
node.physicsBody?.applyForce(vectorForce, asImpulse: true)
```

Comment: This helped me out a lot! I had to switch the X & Y values for my local orientation in the `simd_make_float4` call

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is right. You need to multiply the transform and the direction.
I can't find any documentation on `simd_mul`. But i suspect you have at least one of the following problems:

1. `simd_mul` applies both the rotation and the translation of the transform
2. The transform of the camera is in world coordinate space. Depending your node hierachy this can result in a direction that is way off.

SceneKit does not provide much linear algebra functions, so we have to build our own:

```
extension SCNMatrix4 {
    static public func *(left: SCNMatrix4, right: SCNVector4) -> SCNVector4 {
        let x = left.m11*right.x + left.m21*right.y + left.m31*right.z + left.m41*right.w
        let y = left.m12*right.x + left.m22*right.y + left.m32*right.z + left.m42*right.w
        let z = left.m13*right.x + left.m23*right.y + left.m33*right.z + left.m43*right.w
        let w = left.m14*right.x + left.m24*right.y + left.m43*right.z + left.m44*right.w

        return SCNVector4(x: x, y: y, z: z, w: w)
    }
}
extension SCNVector4 {
    public func to3() -> SCNVector3 {
        return SCNVector3(self.x , self.y, self.z)
    }
}
```

Now do the following:

1. Convert the camera transform to the nodes local coordinate system
2. Create the force as a 4d vector, set the fourth element to 0 to ignore the translation
3. Multiply the transform and the vector

---

```
// Convert the tranform to a SCNMatrix4
let transform = SCNMatrix4FromMat4(currentFrame.camera.transform)
// Convert the matrix to the nodes coordinate space
let localTransform = node.convertTransform(transform, from: nil)

let force = SCNVector4(0, 0, -5, 0)
let rotatedForce = (localTransform * force).to3()

node.physicsBody?.applyForce(rotatedForce, asImpulse: true)
```